Custom Formula for Google Sheet
I am trying to have my table auto assign members as either Alumni or Active based on the year of their graduation and the current date.
Example
Column A = Year of Graduation
Column B = Membership status
I want if column A's date (Year) is lower than today's date (Year) for Column B to say Alumni
If the opposite then column B to say Active
Then have them Highlight the rows that have Active in light a light green.

Conditional values based on current year
Please note that Google Sheets formula cannot do dynamic spilling with computations. To achieve your expected result, you need Google Sheets formula and Conditional formatting.
You can try this Google sheet formula:
=BYROW(A2:A, lambda(x, IF(ISBLANK(x),,IF(x > YEAR(TODAY())-1, "Active", "Alumni"))))

Then you can add conditional formatting to add your desired color whenever the value is set to Active. Here’s the conditional formatting could look like:

Sample dataset and output:

Reference:

Conditional formatting
IF
Year
Byrow


Feel free to try it on your end, and please do not hesitate to provide feedback on how it turns out.
